# undefined method `find_by_friendly_id' with FriendlyId gem and Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, friendly-id

I want to prevent selecting user with his `id` and that's why I am using this method which should work in this way, but instead I am getting this error:

> undefined method `find_by_friendly_id' ...

This is the user model:

```
include FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, :use => [:slugged, :finders]
```

and the controller:

```
def show
    @user= User.find_by_friendly_id(params[:slug])
end
```

I have column `slug` in the table.

I am using latest version of the gem - `5.1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to generate and database slug

```
#rails generate friendly_id
#rake db:migrate
```

## .model

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :permalink, use: [:slugged, :history, :finders]
```

## .controller

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

---

## UPDATED:

I use permalink personally as a sting column.

```
validates_presence_of :permalink
validates_uniqueness_of :permalink, case_sensitive: false
validates :permalink, presence: true, uniqueness: true, :length => {minimum: 4}

def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    permalink_changed?
end
```

Comment: I have this column. With `find` method it works fine. The problem is with `find_by_friendly_id` method which I want to use, because it works only with `slug` for parameter, but not the `id`

Comment: @gdfgdfg why do u want to use `find_by_friendly_id `, and updated my answer ?

Comment: I want because with `find_by_friendly_id`, if you have user/id url (which id is user id) and you pass this id like an argument to the method you will get no results, because it works only with slug. `find` method otherwise works with both - id and slug. If you pass id to find method you will get result. This means user can understand what is his id, which is what I don't want. I have slug column, string type in this table.

Comment: For now I am using `find_by_slug` method provided from `Rails`.